# Differnce between Expect.pm and Telnet.pm

Tags: perl

I am going to start writing a framework from scratch. I am thinking to use Expect.pm or telnet.pm module to connect to remote systems.

As I have worked on both (very basics), I don't know benefits of one module over other.

If someone here knows what is difference and advantages of one over other, please share ideas/thoughts or links where i can research.

Comment: telnet is unencrypted, you shouldn't use it to connect to remote systems. Try one of the ssh modules instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use Expect if I have a lot of Interactive communication with the remote server. Besides, there is a ssh wrapper for expect available on [cpan](http://search.cpan.org/~bnegrao/Net-SSH-Expect-1.09/lib/Net/SSH/Expect.pod)

For a non interactive program , I would use Telnet.

However, I would prefer SSH and key-based authentication to do the job. There are SSH modules available for perl.

Answer (score 0):

Telnet is an **insecure** and old protocol that nobody should be still using. Move into SSH!

From Perl, you have several SSH modules available. My (biased) advice is that you should go for [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aOpenSSH), [Net::SSH2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aSSH2) or [Net::SSH::Any](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aSSH%3a%3aAny).